# I got the serious error When I use asp.net mvc web api to read Oracle Table (data type is CLOB)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Without Data Type is CLOB I can easy to read Oracle Table data , but unfortunately I do got a serious problem when some tables have the CLOB of data type , how can I do .

**Error Message**

> {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The
>   'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json;
>   charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"$id":"2","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError,
>   System.Web.Http","Message":"An error has
>   occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was
>   thrown.","ExceptionType":"System.OutOfMemoryException","StackTrace":" 
>   at System.String.Concat(String str0, String str1)\r\n   at
>   OracleInternal.I18N.Conv.ConvertBytesToString(IList`1 bytes, Int32
>   bytesOffset, Int32 bytesCount, Char[] chars, Boolean
>   bUseReplacementChar)\r\n   at
>   OracleInternal.I18N.Conv.ConvertBytesToString(IList`1 bytes, Char[]
>   chars, Boolean bUseReplacementChar)\r\n   at
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleClobImpl.GetCompleteClobData(Int32
>   currentRow, Int32 columnIndex, OracleConnectionImpl connImpl, Byte[]
>   lobLocator, DataUnmarshaller dataUnmarshaller, TTCLobAccessor
>   lobAccessor, OracleClobImpl& oraClobImpl)\r\n   at
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetString(Int32
>   i)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2
>   constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)\r\n
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter
>   writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object
>   value)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()"}}

PS:
Environment
1. Visual Studio 2015
2. ASP.NET MVC WebApi (entity framework)
3. Oracle 11G
4. use VS default Web API project

Comment: hi did you miss some components , can you check nuget like Entity framework / Oracle etc. that are updated to latest version

Comment: I have updated all latest stable version in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Exception of type
>     'System.OutOfMemoryException' was
>     thrown."

I guess your CLOB object is too big to be transformed. How big is it? Check your available memory during the program execution. Do you have enough free memory?

Based on [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/915567?tstart=0) answer on the Oracle Community looks like there are a couple of issues in the .net driver when CLOB is involved; a suggestion I found there is to try parse the CLOB as a generic BLOB and read it as byte[]. Than you can transform the byte[] to string like this

`string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);`

Comment: thanks you , you are right , the memory was thrown .

Comment: sorry to bother again , In fact the CLOB data don't have many data , for all data capacity just 6MB but my memory has 4G with VM , do you have any idea ,thanks again

Comment: @Luca yes I have the same question , do you have any suggestions ,thank

Comment: I updated the answer with a couple of info I found the oracle community website. May worth a try.